# javascript if giving "undefined" in console

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm sure I'm just overlooking something, but I can't see what it is.

I have a page I'm using to test some new code with using the console. Most of it works.

```
    if(typeof(thisNode.L1.download) != 'undefined') {
    console.log('a1');
        if (thisNode.L1.download.sku.toString() == lastSku) {
            console.log('a2');
            addSku = thisNode.L1.cd.sku.toString();
        } else { console.log('a3'); }
    } else if(typeof(thisNode.S5.download) != 'undefined') {
        console.log('b1');
        if (thisNode.S5.download.sku.toString() == lastSku) {
            console.log('b2');
            addSku = thisNode.S5.cd.sku.toString();
        } else {
            console.log('b3');
        }
    }
    console.log('foo');
```

returns

```
    a1
    a3
    foo
    undefined
```

given that `typeof(thisNode.S5.download) != 'undefined'` returns `true`

and `lastSku` returns `"24536"`

and `thisNode.S5.download.sku.toString()` returns `"24536"`

This is not expected.

I did some breaking down and it looks like it's the initial if statement that is the problem.

I enter into the console: `if (thisNode.L1.download.sku.toString() == lastSku) {}` i get "undefined"

So I checked it piece by piece

`lastSku` returns `"24536"`

`thisNode` returns a JSON object. `Object {L1: Object, S2: Object, S3: Object, S5: Object}`

`thisNode.L1` returns `Object {box: Object, download: Object, cd: Object}`

`thisNode.L1.download` returns `Object {sku: 24354}`

`thisNode.L1.download.sku` returns `24354`

`thisNode.L1.download.sku.toString()` returns `"24354"`

`thisNode.L1.download.sku.toString() == lastSku` returns `false`

```
    if (thisNode.L1.download.sku.toString() == lastSku) {
        console.log('foo');
    } else {
        console.log('bar');
    }
```

returns
        "bar"
        undefined

```
    if (thisNode.L1.download.sku.toString() == lastSku) {
       console.log('foo');
    } else {
        console.log('bar');
    }
    console.log('yabba');
```

returns

```
    bar
    yabba
    undefined
```

Note that I can put any JavaScript in the original if statement and i still get undefined, so it's not that there's no code for it to skip.

To recap, the original block doesn't appear to ever get to line 7 but it does look like after running through the first set of `if` statements it does keep running code after all of them.

Comment: Is that code in a function?  If so, it will output 'undefined' if nothing is returned

Comment: The console *always* prints the value of the last statement evaluated. Block statements have no value (they're `undefined`), as do `var` declarations, `function` declarations, and others.

Answer (score 4):

> I enter into the console: if (thisNode.L1.download.sku.toString() == lastSku) {} i get "undefined"

That's entirely expected behaviour.

The `undefined` you're seeing (and the final `undefined` you're seeing in your larger code examples) is just Chrome's JS console outputting the value the last statement evaluates to, and in JavaScript, `if` statements don't evaluate to a value.

Try this on the console:

```
console.log('foo')
```

You'll see

```
foo
undefined
```

The `foo` is output by `console.log`, the `undefined` is the return value of `console.log`. If you look to the left of `undefined`, you'll see a grey `<-` arrow, indicating this is the return value of the last statement, *not* output caused by the code.

See below:

[image]

This is typical behaviour for [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) environments.

Comment: actually, I do see the undefined. I so focussed on that display that I didn't see the `else if` will never be checked, because, DUH, the first one returned something. I need to restructure this with some `&&` combining the pairs.
I'm not entirely sure what I was thinking by not doing it in the first place.

Comment: @ManofSnow Yes he will, unless you're using a browser where `console.log` returns a value or a console that doesn't output return values in REPL mode.

Comment: @meagar Okay, but I see your edit replaced **for** with **foo**

Comment: @ManofSnow That was corrected 7 minutes ago... Can you explain why you think he "won't see undefined from that"?

Comment: @meager I didn't know the return keyword goes in **if** statements without functions

Answer (score 0):

the `undefined` was a red herring I couldn't stop looking at, which meager helpfully got me to finally see.

The real problem was the external if..else if...else if structure. The reason it never checked `thisNode.S5` was because I used

```
if(typeof(thisNode.L1.download) != 'undefined') {
    if (thisNode.L1.download.sku.toString() == lastSku) {
        //do stuff
    }
else if(typeof(thisNode.S5.download) != 'undefined') {
    if (thisNode.S5.download.sku.toString() == lastSku) {
        //do different stuff
    }
}
```

putting the second check INSIDE the first `if` was a dumb movee. I wasn't thinking. I should, instead, have used

```
if(typeof(thisNode.L1.download) != 'undefined' && thisNode.L1.download.sku.toString() == lastSku) {
    //do stuff
} else if(typeof(thisNode.S3.download) != 'undefined' && thisNode.S5.download.sku.toString() == lastSku) {
    //do different stuff
}
```